# Image not shown in C# code with a href code

Tags: c#, html, css, image

I just want to show image , that is stored in the backend. But the image is not shown. I get this error:

```
downloadIcon.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/hepchat/images/downloadIcon.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I do it like this:

```
 return $"<a href = \"{baseUrl}api/Devices/GetDownload/{model.AttachmentKey}/\" class=\"msgdownload\"><img src='./images/downloadIcon.jpg' alt=\"Download\"/></a>";
```

And I have a css class like this:

```
.msgdownload {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;

}

.msgdownload::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And I dont want to do in the css class something like this:

```
background: url(../hepchat/images/download.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
```

Because then I cant have alternative text, when the image is not found.

Thank you.

Comment: What I do wrong? Thank you. I have just the image in the folder images

Comment: Has somebody any advise? Thank you

Comment: Where are you storing the image URL? Also can you show me how you are storing the images to your folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by putting the image to the `/src/assets` folder.
Something like:

```
/src/assets/hepchat/images/downloadIcon.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. But I dont want it to have it in css